# Problems with plotting exponential curve and data in the same plot when values are high

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, ggplot2

I am running exponential regression on my data, but when trying to plot the curve I get a Inf problem because the independent variable values seem to be too high. How can I solve this in order to be able to plot the real values of the independent variable and the regression line incl standard errors in the same plot?

`DPUT` of my data:

```
structure(list(YR = c(1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 
1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 
1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 
1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), count = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 7L, 10L, 
12L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 16L, 21L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 18L, 19L, 
14L, 14L, 13L, 21L, 20L, 18L, 28L, 21L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 
34L, 37L, 31L, 59L, 45L, 49L, 42L, 48L, 65L, 52L, 62L, 49L)), .Names =
c("YR", "count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 27:83)
```

And my script:

```
ggplot(data.df,aes(x=YR,y=count)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,75),breaks=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70),expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1960,2018),breaks=c(1960,1965,1970,
                                              1975,1980,1985,1990,1995,
                                              2000,2005,2010,2015)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',width=0.8) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~exp(x),se=T, col=2) +
  xlab(" ") + ylab("count")
```

Comment: I disaggree with the close votes. OP has a statistical issue disguised by their programming problems. This question at its heart is on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong model. You should not transform the x-variable, but log-transform the y-variable to fit an exponential model with `lm`. That's not possible within ggplot2.

However, judging from your variable names, you have count data. A Poisson GLM seems a better choice then:

```
library(ggplot2)
mod <- glm(count~YR, data = data.df, family = "poisson")
pred.df <- data.frame(YR = seq(min(data.df$YR), max(data.df$YR), length.out = 100))
pred <- predict(mod, newdata = pred.df, se.fit = TRUE)
pred.df$count <- exp(pred$fit)
pred.df$countmin <- exp(pred$fit - 2 * pred$se.fit)
pred.df$countmax <- exp(pred$fit + 2 * pred$se.fit)
```

I also see absolutely no good reason to make a barplot for this data. Points can depict the data much better.

```
ggplot(data.df,aes(x=YR,y=count)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,75),breaks=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70),expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1960,2018),breaks=c(1960,1965,1970,
                                                  1975,1980,1985,1990,1995,
                                                  2000,2005,2010,2015)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(data = pred.df, aes(ymin = countmin, ymax = countmax), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(data = pred.df) +
  xlab(" ") + ylab("count")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Note that you also have a time series and should check for autocorrelation of residuals (which appears to be rather pronounced) and use an appropriate model for time series instead. (Also check for over/underdispersion as part of the model diagnostics and change to a more appropriate GLM if necessary.).

You should also study [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/204697/11849).