# calculate probability of earthquake in the next 5 years by data given

Tags: r, probability

I have the following data for earthquake magnitudes in a specific country in the years of 2006 to 2015 (years not mentioned had 0 earthquakes of magnitude equal or more than 7)

```
year         count
<int>        <int>
2011             1          
2013             2          
2015             1
```

the question I want to answer is the probability of an earthquake, happening with magnitude of equal or greater than 7 in the next 5 years.

I found this link about [Gutenberg-Richter law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutenberg%E2%80%93Richter_law) but I can't find a good model to compute the probability.

I'm programming the probability in R and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), a [common choice of distribution for count data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204696/what-regression-model-is-the-most-appropriate-to-use-with-count-data/204698#204698), the four earthquakes in ten years lead to maximum likelihood estimate of rate of earthquakes per year

$$\hat \lambda = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n k_i}{n} = \frac{4}{10}$$

where $k_i$ is the number of earthquakes in the $i$-th year. This leads to estimating probability of any earthquake in a single year as

$$\Pr(K \ge 1) = 1 - \Pr(K=0) = 1 - e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} = 1 - e^{-0.4} = 0.33$$

Assuming independence between years, the probability of any earthquake in five years is equal to

$$
\underbrace{1-\underbrace{\big(\Pr(K=0)\big)^5}_\text{no earthquake in 5 years}}_\text{opposite of the above} = 1-0.67^5=0.86
$$

Notice that this result is consistent with much simpler approach: observe that, according to your data, probability of observing a year with any earthquake is $3/10$, so probability of observing at least one such year in five is $1-(1-3/10)^5$.

I guess, there may exist more seismologically-correct approaches to such problem, but this is a simple probabilistic approach, since you asked on the stats site.