# Unrealistic coefficients when comparing two count samples with glm poisson

Tags: generalized-linear-model, count-data

I would like to test the significance of the difference in mean between two independent count samples. I'm doing this with a GLM poisson in R, as shown in the code below:

```
a=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
b=c(1,2,0,1,1,2,0,1,0,2)

c=data.frame(sp=c(a,b),grp=c(rep('A',10),rep('B',10)))

summary(glm(sp~grp,data=c,family=poisson))

Call:
glm(formula = sp ~ grp, family = poisson, data = c)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.41421  -0.00006  -0.00006   0.00000   0.87897  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    -20.3     4914.8  -0.004    0.997
grpB            20.3     4914.8   0.004    0.997

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 22.1807  on 19  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  8.3178  on 18  degrees of freedom
AIC: 28.159

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
```

As you can see, the coefficient values are not reflecting reality. I noticed that this happened because group "A" has mean=0.
In this way, I would like to know if there is any way to fix this problem in glm, or if there is any other better method to test my hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

The expected value predicted by [Poisson regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204696/what-regression-model-is-the-most-appropriate-to-use-with-count-data/204698#204698) is

$$
E[y|X,\beta] = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}
$$

assuming we're using the standard log link function. So your model predicts:

```r
> beta <- c(-20.3, 20.3)
> exp(beta[1] + beta[2] * 0)
[1] 1.52694e-09
> exp(beta[1] + beta[2] * 1)
[1] 1
> mean(a)
[1] 0
> mean(b)
[1] 1
```

I would say that there's nothing wrong with the predictions. The only issue is that you are assuming [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) for a group that has zero mean, while the distribution is parametrized by $\lambda \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If willing to do an alternative test, here is code to do an [E-test for the difference in Poisson means](http://www.ucs.louisiana.edu/%7Ekxk4695/JSPI-04.pdf):

```
# Forgive me, will make putting this in a package on my ToDo list
source('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/r4zmlxmi41tqsts/ETest.R?dl=0')
poisson.etest(0,10,10,10)
```

Which returns a p-value of `0.0005782135`.

If you want/need to stick with GLM's, it is common for logistic regression to use penalized regression for perfectly separated data. It *may* also make sense here for Poisson, although there isn't an obvious default for the penalties, nor am I sure about how the standard errors/coverage for coefficients will behave.