# GLM negative binomial - what to do when one category has only zeros?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, negative-binomial-distribution

I have camera trap data for four different management types (A,B,C,D). I want to know whether there is an effect of these management types on the abundance of different mammalian herbivore species.

For some of the species, there are only zeros in one type of management,  which complicates the analysis.

What do I do? I know I could do a Bayesian approach but before I go into that, I would like to know if there's a work-around that allows me to do this analysis using a frequentist approach.

The data for zebras:

```r
    counts <- (c(67, 194, 155, 135, 146, 257, 114, 134, 111, 87, 
               62, 67, 85, 89, 63, 86, 97, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    management <- rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 6)
```

The model:

```r
     library(MASS)
     model <- glm.nb(counts ~ management)
     summary(model)
```

The output shows a huge standard error for group D, that only had 0s:

```r
    Call:
    glm.nb(formula = counts ~ management, init.theta = 
       11.27380856, 
        link = log)
    
    Deviance Residuals: 
         Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
    -2.42149  -0.35526  -0.00006   0.45934   1.70106  
    
    Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)    5.0689     0.1258  40.286  < 2e-16 ***
    managementB   -0.5063     0.1799  -2.815  0.00488 ** 
    managementC   -0.7208     0.1810  -3.982 6.84e-05 ***
    managementD  -25.3715  6344.9393  -0.004  0.99681    
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    (Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(11.2738) family taken to be 1)
    
        Null deviance: 339.360  on 23  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance:  18.139  on 20  degrees of freedom
    AIC: 185.92
    
    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1
    
    
                  Theta:  11.27 
              Std. Err.:  4.11 
    
     2 x log-likelihood:  -175.918
```

It can also not show me any differences between 'D' and all the other groups.
pairwise comparison:

```r
    library(multcomp)
    contrasts <- c(
      "A - B = 0",
      "A - C = 0",
      "A - D = 0",
      "B - C = 0",
      "B - D = 0",
      "C - D = 0")
    
    H <- glht(model, linfct = mcp(management = contrasts))
    summary(H)

    Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
    
    Multiple Comparisons of Means: User-defined Contrasts
       
    Fit: glm.nb(formula = counts ~ management, init.theta = 
          11.27380856, 
        link = log)
    
    Linear Hypotheses:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    A - B == 0    0.5063     0.1799   2.815 0.018355 *  
    A - C == 0    0.7208     0.1810   3.982 0.000271 ***
    A - D == 0   25.3715  6344.9393   0.004 1.000000    
    B - C == 0    0.2145     0.1829   1.173 0.597425    
    B - D == 0   24.8652  6344.9393   0.004 1.000000    
    C - D == 0   24.6507  6344.9393   0.004 1.000000    
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Comment: A one-line answer to your statistical question ("whether there is an effect of these management types on the abundance") is given by  `kruskal.test(counts, factor(management))`

Comment: There is absolutely no serious problem with zeros in negative binomial regression. The only problem is that you are relying on Wald tests, which do not work when the parameter estimates become infinite. The solution is to use likelihood ratio tests instead (i.e., use the `anova` function to test hypotheses instead of t-tests) and the apparent problems will disappear. The D group will then be significantly different. This is a known problem with a known solution that occurs for binomial, Poisson or negative binomial families.

Comment: Example of `anova` solution for logistic regression: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315684/i-think-my-logistic-model-is-overfitted-even-with-lasso-r-gives-me-a-perfect-se/315691#315691 . The NB glm with zeros in one group may seem different to logistic regression but it is really the same issue -- the zeros are fitted exactly and the linear model coefficient becomes infinite.

Comment: Is there a way to test for differences between management groups?

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the other answers with some experimental calculations. The large standard error for `managementD` is caused by small sample size. The standard error you've got is based on an approximation, based on the loglikelihood function being approximately quadratic, which it is not. We can try to get a confidence interval by profiling, but the R `profile` function do not work with `glm.nb`, so I try a workaround using the package `bbmle`:

```r
counts <- (c(67, 194, 155, 135, 146, 257, 114, 134, 111, 87, 
               62, 67, 85, 89, 63, 86, 97, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
management <- rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 6)

mydf <- data.frame(counts, management)

model.bbmle <- mle2(counts ~ dnbinom(mu=exp(logmu), size=exp(logtheta)),
                    method= "BFGS", parameters=list(logmu ~ 0 +  
                       management),
                    data=mydf, start=list(logmu=0, 
                      logtheta=2.42),
                    control=list(trace=1)  )

summary(model.bbmle)
Maximum likelihood estimation

Call:
mle2(minuslogl = counts ~ dnbinom(mu = exp(logmu), size = exp(logtheta)), 
    start = list(logmu = 0, logtheta = 2.42), method = "BFGS", 
    data = mydf, parameters = list(logmu ~ 0 + management), control = list(trace = 1))

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value     Pr(z)    
logmu.managementA   5.06898    0.12585 40.2783 < 2.2e-16 ***
logmu.managementB   4.56265    0.12856 35.4897 < 2.2e-16 ***
logmu.managementC   4.34811    0.13017 33.4038 < 2.2e-16 ***
logmu.managementD -11.55880  132.09516 -0.0875    0.9303    
logtheta            2.42213    0.36435  6.6478 2.976e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

-2 log L: 175.9181
```

The fit is comparable to yours with `glm.nb`, the maximized loglikelihood is equal, (note the changed parametrization), the standard error is lower, but still huge!

Now, we can try profiling, but this do not work very well, so I will only give the code:

```r
prof.4 <- bbmle::profile(model.bbmle, which=4, maxsteps=1000, 
                 alpha=0.005, trace=TRUE)  

 confint(prof.4)

    2.5 %    97.5 % 
       NA -89.53398 
 Warning messages:
 1: In .local(object, parm, level, ...) :
   non-monotonic spline fit to profile (logmu.managementD):  reverting from spline to linear approximation
 2: In regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), 
      na.rm = na.rm) :
  collapsing to unique 'x' values
```

The returned interval (remember log scale!) do not make sense, and we will soon understand why. I will show a plot of a section of the loglikelihood function, along the `D` axes (this is not the same as profiling, since the other parameters are held fixed). This is some ugly code I do not fully understand (caused by `bbmle`using S4 object system):

```r
B <- coef(model.bbmle)

minuslogl_0 <- slot(model.bbmle, "minuslogl")

minuslogl <- function(B) do.call("minuslogl_0", namedrop(as.list(B)))
```

But now we can make a plot of a section of the minusloglikelihood function along the `D` axes, where the other parameters are held at the maxlik estimated values:

[image: Section of negative loglikelihood function]

on the `x`axis is the deviation of the `D` parameter from its maxlik value. One can see that no lower bound can be set (or, on the original scale, 0 is the lower bound), but a sharp upper bound an be set, and it will be smaller than what indicated by the standard error calculation. The code used is

```r
delta <- 10
plot( Vectorize( function(x) minuslogl(B + c(0, 0, 0, x, 0)) ),  
     from=-delta, to=delta, ylab="minusloglik", 
     main="Section of negative loglikelihood function",
     col="red")
```

Answer (score 3):

I dissent somewhat from the first answer by @dariober.

1. Adding 1 is a fudge.
2. There is no substantive reason for disbelieving zeros as recorded in the sample.
3. Most important, model fits are reasonable, the only oddity being the rather wide confidence intervals in one case. There is some robustness, as  Poisson and negative binomial fits are essentially identical in fitted values. (Indeed, for this structure, all plausible models, and some not so plausible ones, essentially return group means as fitted values. The only differences are inferential small print, and if you're queasy about this you really need a bigger dataset! Easy to say....)

A graph shows it all:

[image]

For completeness, here is the Stata code I used. Naturally, the calculations are simple in any modern statistical environment.

```
clear 
mat counts = (67,194,155,135,146,257,114,134,111,87,62,67,85,89,63,86,97,44,0,0,0,0,0,0)
set obs 24
gen counts = counts[1, _n]
egen management = seq(), block(6)
label define management 1 A 2 B 3 C 4 D
label val management management

glm counts i.management , family(poisson)
predict poisson
glm counts i.management , family(nbinomial)
predict nbinomial 

* uncomment next if you need to install 
* ssc install stripplot 

gen management1 = management - 0.1
gen management2 = management - 0.2 

stripplot counts , over(management)  vertical stack height(0.3) legend(on order(1 "data" 2 "Poisson fit" 3 "Negative binomial fit")) yla(, ang(h)) ///
addplot(scatter poisson management2, ms(D) || scatter nbinomial management1, ms(T))
```

EDIT For a slightly less *ad hoc* method of injecting Bayes flavour than just adding 1 to all counts, I used quasi-Bayes smoothing as suggested by I.J. Good (for a self-contained account see [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0168); typo fix within [this paper, pp.494-495](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0039)) before pushing those adjusted counts through a Poisson GLM (using robust (sandwich-Huber-Eicker-White) standard errors). The P-values make more sense while at the same time predicted means are not that different from any other fit. There will be other and arguably better ways to do this.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
  management |       mean     Poisson   nbinomial  qs_Poisson
-------------+-----------------------------------------------
           A |      159.0       159.0       159.0       157.7
           B |       95.8        95.8        95.8        95.6
           C |       77.3        77.3        77.3        77.4
           D |        0.0         0.0         0.0         1.5
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Sure my solution can be improved but I still think it is a viable one that requires virtually no changes to what the OP already has (in contrast to a Bayesian solution that would need a different framework). I think adding +1 is akin to using a prior that makes extreme coefficients unlikely. In fact, it's possible that the estimate for group D after adding +1 (-5.07) is more reasonable than the original one (-25). I think +1 could be seen as a simple form of regularization.

Comment: (Thanks for the edit) From a practical point of view, I see a tradeoff between quality of results and complexity of analysis. My dumb "add 1" solution is very simple and easy to explain. Nevertheless, I surmise that results are going to be very comparable to sophisticated solutions that would be opaque to non-experts and prone to misuse. With 6 datapoints, all zero, there is not much you can do anyway without some *ad hoc* assumptions (I don't mean to encourage sloppy behaviour of course...)

Comment: If very simple and easy to explain is the criterion (and it's a criterion I like; I am not a statistician and my colleagues really aren't) then Kruskal-Wallis or plain ANOVA  or just look at a graph! beats anything you or I propose.  But the OP is starting from a GLM and that's where we start.  I don't think "add 1" is easy to explain. What is easy to explain is that you might expect to see more animals if you observed longer -- but then if 0s might easily be 1s then 200+ should be expected to be many more than 1 greater.

Comment: Naturally we are assuming that nothing about management D makes seeing zebras **impossible**. If those zeros are fixed or structural, then the analysis needs to be different.

Comment: I think your comments are in line with mine. Simplicity is just *a* criterion that you need to balance against others. It may be that Kruskal-Wallis or a plot are too simple for the OP. It's exactly because the OP starts with negbin GLM that "+1" fits nicely, s/he doesn't need to change anything and it may be good enough. Regarding the (im)possibility of zero counts, this is up to the OP to decide - the "+1" solution makes it clear that you reject this possibility and you go for a rough approximation of what the lower bound could be. (Thanks for engaging in the conversation BTW)

Comment: Agreed with that in essence. Given that our positions are close, I've modified the opening wording of my answer.  I'd guess that the OP is a researcher who knows some statistics who may well need to explain results to people who know less. My own role is often similar.

Comment: Another [similar question recently](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/539212/1036). If one is dead set on the GLM approach, I've wondered if something akin to Firth for logit would work here, so just penalize the coefficients a wee bit (which is not the same as adding +1, bit of a kludge that is). But in the end any ratio stat will not make sense -- seems a bit of a non-problem to me though (only occurs if you artificially limit yourself to only interpreting confidence intervals post-hoc a regression model).

Comment: @AndyW The dataset as usual permits several different analyses. To me a graph of raw data tells the main story simply, but for all we know the OP (or someone else with similar data)  is (or might be) under orders to do inference too, in which case more should be said and starting with the fact that we have heteroscedastic counts leads directly to GLMs in the first instance. Another answer fleshing out your idea would be a welcome addition an already lively thread.

Comment: Nick is right in that I am basically under 'order' to show the differences between the groups. The ghlt function doesn't work so until now I don't see a solution yet other than the +1.

Comment: See @Gordon Smyth’s comments.

Comment: Gordon's comments did not provide any workable example. Im not sure how to proceed. Could you give any direction?

Comment: See his link, which gives R code in an example.  I am not a person to advise on R code.

Answer (score 1):

As requested by the OP in comments, I'm going to give an example in R of  applying likelihood ratio test (LRT) to test differences between management groups as suggested by @GordonSmyth. I'm not sure I'm getting this right so please check it - credit goes to Gordon, faults are mine.

With LRT we check for significant differences between nested models. To apply it to this case, we need to expand the factors in `management` to a matrix (I guess `glm` does this internally anyway). Then we can drop each factor in turn and see if the simpler model differs from the full one:

```
library(MASS)

counts <- c(67, 194, 155, 135, 146, 257, 114, 134, 111, 87, 
            62, 67, 85, 89, 63, 86, 97, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

management <- rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 6)

design <- model.matrix(~ management)
design
   (Intercept) managementB managementC managementD
1            1           0           0           0
2            1           0           0           0
3            1           0           0           0
4            1           0           0           0
5            1           0           0           0
6            1           0           0           0
7            1           1           0           0
8            1           1           0           0
9            1           1           0           0
10           1           1           0           0
11           1           1           0           0
12           1           1           0           0
13           1           0           1           0
14           1           0           1           0
15           1           0           1           0
16           1           0           1           0
17           1           0           1           0
18           1           0           1           0
19           1           0           0           1
20           1           0           0           1
21           1           0           0           1
22           1           0           0           1
23           1           0           0           1
24           1           0           0           1
```

Fit the full model, we tell `glm.nb` to omit the intercept since this is already encoded in the design matrix. You may want to check that this is the same using `glm.nb(counts ~ management)`:

```
fit_full <- glm.nb(counts ~ 0 + design)
```

Now we drop group B, fit the reduced model and compare with the full one. This should be equivalent to assessing the significance of difference  difference group A and group B. We get a p-value of ~0.01:

```
design_red <- design[, - which(colnames(design) == 'managementB')]
fit_red <-  glm.nb(counts ~ 0 + design_red)
anova(fit_full, fit_red)

Likelihood ratio tests of Negative Binomial Models

Response: counts
           Model  theta Resid. df    2 x log-lik.   Test    df LR stat. Pr(Chi)
1 0 + design_red  7.668        21          -182.4                              
2     0 + design 11.274        20          -175.9 1 vs 2     1    6.531  0.0106
```

We can do the same for group D:

```
design_red <- design[, - which(colnames(design) == 'managementD')]
fit_red <-  glm.nb(counts ~ 0 + design_red)
anova(fit_full, fit_red)
Likelihood ratio tests of Negative Binomial Models

Response: counts
           Model     theta Resid. df    2 x log-lik.   Test    df LR stat. Pr(Chi)
1 0 + design_red 829670.23        21         -1640.8                              
2     0 + design     11.27        20          -175.9 1 vs 2     1     1465       0
```

Unsurprisingly, the p-value for the difference between A and D is next to 0. Note that the theta parameter for the reduced model is huge and `glm.nb` issues warnings. I'm not sure how to interpret these but I guess it's not surprising since the intercept includes large-ish values with a string of zeros.

To test the difference between, say, B and C I would recode the full matrix to use B instead of A as intercept and proceed as above - I think there are better ways though.

Hope this helps and I got it right. However, I still think my other solution adding pseudocounts is worth considering.

Comment: Thank you! Im going to think about the two solutions

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation of why this is happening see [GLM for count data with all zeroes in one category](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381915/glm-for-count-data-with-all-zeroes-in-one-category).

> I know I could do a bayesian approach but before I go into that, I would like to know if there's a work-around that allows me to do this analysis using a frequentist

I think you could just add 1 to all observations and then get sensible estimates:

```r
model <- glm.nb(counts+1 ~ management)
> summary(model)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = counts + 1 ~ management, init.theta = 
       11.87310622, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.4588  -0.3605   0.0000   0.4648   1.7339  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   5.0752     0.1228  41.330  < 2e-16 ***
managementB  -0.5022     0.1756  -2.860  0.00424 ** 
managementC  -0.7142     0.1768  -4.041 5.33e-05 ***
managementD  -5.0752     0.4425 -11.470  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(11.8731) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 310.516  on 23  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  18.652  on 20  degrees of freedom
AIC: 198.44

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1

              Theta:  11.87 
          Std. Err.:  4.23 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -188.443
```

The rationale would be that zeros are not really a possible outcome and they are just a consequence of the sampling. By adding 1 you reset to a more realistic lower bound. Of course, this is acceptable if adding 1 doesn't skew the dataset too much, which doesn't seem to be the case here. I think the logic is not too dissimilar from a Bayesian approach.

---

I add simulation results to illustrate the effect of adding 1 to the raw counts. Incidentally, I think this also illustrates the tradeoff between [bias and variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff).

I keep the counts for groups A, B, and C constant (I don't think this matters here). For group D I simulate counts from a negative binomial distribution with varying mean and size. Then I fit the `glm.nb` model with and without adding 1. For simplicity, I made group D to be the intercept.

Here's a summary plot of the estimates for group D, note that I reset the estimates below -10 to -10 for ease of visualization:

[image]

Horizontal lines are the true means. Each box is 500 simulations.

- When the true mean is very low (about < 1), the estimates from corrected counts noticeably overestimate the true mean (they are biased) but they are very consistent between replicates (low variance).
- Conversely, with low means, the estimates from raw counts are very unstable between replicates (high variance). After repeating the same experiment you could get considerably different results.
- When the true mean is above about 5, the effect of adding 1 starts vanishing.

I think it's up to the analyst to decide how to proceed but by gut feeling I would say that adding 1 "make sense" here. I think the issue is not so much the numerical stability of the uncorrected estimates but rather whether they are meaningful.

Code:

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

counts <- c(67, 194, 155, 135, 146, 257, 114, 134, 111, 87, 62, 
       67, 85, 89, 63, 86, 97, 44)
management <- rep(LETTERS[1:4], c(6, 6, 6, 6))
management <- relevel(as.factor(management), ref= 'D')

seed <- 1
dat <- list()
for(i in 1:500) {
    for(mu in c(0.1, 1, 5, 10)) {
        for(size in c(0.1, 1, 10)) {
            set.seed(seed)
            d <- data.table(
                seed= seed,
                mu= mu,
                size= size,
                counts= c(counts, rnbinom(n= sum(
                 management == 'D'), mu= mu, size= size)),
                management= management
            )
            dat[[length(dat) + 1]] <- d
            seed <- seed + 1
        }
    }
}
dat <- rbindlist(dat)

estimates <- dat[, list(raw= coef(glm.nb(counts ~   
    management))[1], corrected= coef(glm.nb(counts + 1 ~ 
    management))[1]), by= list(seed, mu, size)]
estimates <- melt(estimates, id.vars= c('seed', 'mu', 'size'), variable.name= 'method', value.name= 'estimate')

estimates[, label := sprintf('True mean count= %s', mu)]
estimates[, label := factor(label, sprintf('True mean count= %s', unique(sort(mu))))]
gg <- ggplot(data= estimates, aes(x= as.factor(size), y= 
      ifelse(estimate < -10, -10, estimate), colour= method)) +
        geom_hline(data= unique(estimates[,list(mu, label)]), 
      aes(yintercept= log(mu)), colour= 'grey30', 
      linetype= 'dashed') +
        geom_boxplot() +
        xlab('Size (dispersion parameter)') +
        ylab('Estimate (capped to -10)') +
        theme_light() +
        theme(strip.text= element_text(colour= 'black', 
        size= 12)) +
        facet_wrap(~ label, scales= 'free_y')
```

---

EDIT: I see quite a bit of skepticism about this solution and I'm slightly surprised about it since adding 1 to count data is not unheard of.

For example, gene expression data from sequencing technology come as count data. A very respected method of differential expression analysis is limma-voom (Gordon Smyth is a coauthor, my apologies if I'm misquoting). From the [paper](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/gb-2014-15-2-r29):

> The counts are offset away from zero by 0.5 to avoid taking the log of zero, and to reduce the variability of log-cpm for low expression genes.

This is exactly what I'm proposing here.

Gene expression is never really zero and the difference between a count of 0 and a count of 1 is biologically irrelevant anyway, typically. Is it the same for the OP's case? I don't know but I suspect it is. Does it really matter whether group D has exactly 0 zebras or just 1 or 2 that went undetected in just 6 observations? If the answer is no, then adding 1 is more sensible than producing -Inf coefficients.

Comment: Thanks,  this makes sense!

Comment: (I don't agree with adding 1 as a good solution, but the downvote by someone else is poor show without an explanation.)

Comment: @NickCox thanks for the comment! I feel I'm punching way above my weight here. I edited my answer with an addition to try to give it more backup. LIvely discussion indeed, I'm enjoying it!

Comment: But the $-\infty$ coefficients is on the link (that is, log) scale, so represents a mean of zero, which is reasonable! (I will try to add to my answer)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sure, it's possible that there are no zebras at all and the mean can only be zero. But given only 6 observations, I think it's more reasonable to say that the mean is "very low". As I show in the simulations, you get more stable estimates for a relatively small price in terms of bias. I think it depends on whether you care about the difference between "very low" and "exactly zero" (for gene expression, you don't care)