# Can I Use the loo function to help me choose between a Poisson and Bernouilli distribution in bayesian

Tags: r, bayesian, brms

I have two models exactly similar, but I’m using a Poisson distribution for one and a Bernoulli distribution for the other. Can I trust the information coming out of loo to help me choose?

The Bernoulli model comes on top.

```html
rbpa <- brm(status ~ ... , family = poisson(), prior = 
            set_prior('normal(0, 4)', class = 'b'),  
            cores = 6, iter = 4000)

rbba <- brm(status ~ ... , family = bernoulli, 
            prior(normal(0, 4), class = b), cores = 6, 
            iter = 4000)

loo(rbpa,rbba)
```

Comment: This isn‘t a coding question, but a statistics question. You‘ll probably find answers on Cross Validated.

Comment: This question was answer here: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/using-loo-function-to-help-me-choose-a-distribution/25511

Comment: What's your response variable?  Bernoulli is for binary data and Poisson is for count data.

Answer (score 0):

Methods for model selection like `loo` have nothing to do with the problem. [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) distribution is a distribution for the binary variable (0's or 1's) while [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) distribution can take any non-negative integers like [counts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204696/what-regression-model-is-the-most-appropriate-to-use-with-count-data/204698#204698). You *can't* use Bernoulli distribution instead of Poisson or the other way around.