# Split linear predictors with link function

Tags: generalized-linear-model, predictor, link-function

Is it possible to split linear predictors contribution up when talking glm of non-normal distributions?

If:
$$µ_i = g^{-1}(η_i)$$
and
$$µ_i = g^{-1}(β_0 + β_1X_{i1} + β_2X_{i2} +···+β_kX_{ik})$$

Is it then possible to split $µ_i$ up based on predictors? For instance, is this valid? : $$µ^{intercept}_i + µ_i^{predictor\ 1}= g^{-1}(β_0)\ + g^{-1}(β_1X_{i1})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** Link functions are in most cases (except identity link) non-linear functions, so this won't work. Take as an example [Poisson regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204696/what-regression-model-is-the-most-appropriate-to-use-with-count-data/204698#204698) that predicts

$$
E[Y|X] = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \dots + \beta_k X_k}
$$

by the properties of the [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) this translates to a multiplicative relationship

$$
E[Y|X] = e^{\beta_0}  e^{\beta_1 X_1} \dots e^{\beta_k X_k}
$$

and it is one of the link functions where this relationship is the least ugly.